# SRV record lookup for Facebook failing on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I do a lookup using 'dig' from my EC2 instance for chat.facebook.com's SRV record it doesnt return a result. The same lookup works from desktop. SRV lookup for other domains work fine from EC2 - just not facebook

**ON EC2**

```
$> dig chat.facebook.com srv

; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> chat.facebook.com srv
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 44348
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;chat.facebook.com.     IN  SRV

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.0.23#53(172.16.0.23)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 16 12:53:35 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 35
```

**ON DESKTOP**

```
$> dig chat.facebook.com srv
; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> chat.facebook.com srv
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26056
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;chat.facebook.com.     IN  SRV

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
facebook.com.       60  IN  SOA glb1.facebook.com. hostmaster.facebook.com. 3909 10800 3600 604800 60

;; Query time: 329 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.41.5#53(172.16.41.5)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 16 18:14:33 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EC2 - Is an Ubuntu Server 10.10 instance.

Comment: Apparently, the Amazon DNS servers don't have an entry for chat.facebook.com - i think. I changed my nameservers to google's and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

facebook is responding with a CNAME instead of a RFC standard A record. Versions of BIND are not allowing this.